# Most elegant variadic functor

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

**Question**

> Suppose we have two sorts of classes
>
> - an input class `Input`
>
>   - defines a type `result_type`
>   - defines `set(result_type)`
> - an output class `Output`
>
>   - defines a type `result_type`
>   - defines `result_type get() const`
>   - has a number of `Input` classes as member variables, on which its output depends
>
> Given an output class and several input classes (arbitrary number),
>   consider the following procedure:
>
> - loop over each input class and call `set()` with an appropriate value (defined beforehand)
> - call the `get()` on the ouput class and collect the result.
>
> This procedure can be seen as a call to a function taking the input's
>   values as arguments an returning the output value.
>
> **Write the functor that constructs such a variadic function in the general case.**
>
> Constraints are: C++ (most likely C++11), arbitrary number of input
>   classes of possibly different `Input::result_type`s. Note that
>   `Input::result_type` is not necessarily related to
>   `Output::result_type`. Aim should first be efficiency, but there's a
>   big bonus if the code is elegant and readable.
>
> *Details*: For those who wonder how `Output` is related to `Input`, one could imagine that `Input` has a `result_type get() const` method
>   as well, which returns whatever you provided via `set()`. `Output`
>   then has a constructor that takes various `Input`s, and stores them
>   (or their reference) as member variables. `Output::get()` then does
>   some math by using the return values of its input's `get()` methods,
>   and returns some result of type `Output::result_type`.

**Proposed solution**

```
#include <functional>

template <class Output, class... Inputs>
std::function<typename Output::result_type(typename Inputs::result_type...)>
make_function(const Output& output, Inputs&... inputs) {
  return[&](typename Inputs::result_type... input_vals) {
    int dummy[]{0, (inputs.set(input_vals),0)...};
    return output.get();
  };
}
```

The `int dummy[]` line is due to [@ecatmur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515637/958110).

Comment: Just as a question, how are the arbitrary number of `Inputs` stored in `Output`?

Comment: there are multiple classes that have a fixed number of inputs, and each store them in a similar way (see details section).

Comment: Ok. I was asking because if they are all the same type, then I think there is a more elegant solution. Having them be heterogeneous types makes it more difficult, however. I might think about it a bit more, but I will say that if you're looking for efficiency, I'd try and avoid `std::function` if possible.

Comment: by what would you replace `std::function` then?

Comment: In this case, you likely don't have a choice without changing the design significantly. In C++14, this may change with generic lambdas. That being said, having thought about it, I don't think this can really be improved upon.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as if you've already got the most elegant solution in mind.

In C++14 you'd remove the dependency on `std::function` and simply return a naked lambda, like this:

```
template <class Output, class... Inputs>
auto make_function(const Output& output, Inputs&... inputs) {
  return [&](typename Inputs::result_type... input_vals) {
    int dummy[] { 0, ((void)inputs.set(input_vals),0)... };
    return output.get();
  };
}
```

but in C++11 you can't make a function-that-returns-a-naked-lambda without a ton of boilerplate — if it's even possible at all.

---

Also, a nitpick, with props to @stephan-t-lavavej's talk at CppCon 2014. You wrote

```
(inputs.set(input_vals),0)...
```

but what you should have written was

```
((void)inputs.set(input_vals),0)...
```

to avoid accidentally calling `MaliciousUserCode::operator,(int)`.